# applying CSS to the IDs that are created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem applying CSS to ID that are created dynamically in my Javascript (using DOM). I have a code which creates 'div' blocks and their respective IDs. The IDs look something like this cg1cp1, cg2cp1, cg3cp2, cg3cp3etc... based on the user input (I have counters to generate them and it goes on indefinitely until the user stops clicking and creating new ones). In another section of 'div' blocks where the ID go like this cg1, cg2, cg2, cg4,... etc. I've managed to apply CSS specifically to these by using code that looks something like this

```
    <style>
        [id^="cg"]{
            position : relative;
            top : 10px;
        }
    </style>
```

So I was wondering if there are any CSS constructs that can be used to apply CSS to variable IDs.

Comment: If you are creating the elements in JS, why don't you just add class 1+ class names to the elements upon creation?

Comment: Why not change the css in your js? like this: `$("#myId"+cg).css({position:"relative", top:10+"px"});` or add a class as @Eclecticist mentioned using `$("#myId"+cg).addClass("myClassName");` where myClassName is a class with properties in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use classes :) just add the same class to all ids of the same group:

```
element.id = 'cg' + i + 'cp' + j
element.classList.add('cgcp')
```

Then on your css:

```
.cgcp { color: red; }
```

Comment: @user3547407 since it works, can you upvote his answer please.

Comment: Oh. It says I don't have enough reputation to upvote :( How do we increase this reputation :D Sorry completely parallel question.